# Does The Last of Us disc version install to hard drive?

Tags: the-last-of-us

Does The Last of Us disc version install its contents to the PS3 hard drive?

This game has horrible loading times for single and multiplayer.

Comment: I gather from your question, that you own the game. Why not try it and see?

Comment: Does any PS3 game install to hard drive?

Comment: @deutschZuid Yes. Some games will install a block of game assets to the hard disk, such as Gran Turismo 5 and Devil May Cry 4. I haven't come across any game which install completely to the disk, allowing disk free play though.

Comment: @deutschZuid There are games (mostly Beat 'em Ups), where you can choose to install the game to the HDD, games (e.g. Deus Ex or Dishonored) where you have to wait for the game to install when you first start it, and games (e.g. Uncharted or TLoU), that don't install anything. Metal Gear Solid 4 used to install all data for one act (out of 5) and replaced the previously installed act; with the latest update, it keeps the previously installed acts and also gives you an option to install all acts at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The game does not install any assets to the hard disk.

Once you are past the intro and have loaded a game, the loading times from there are not that long, it's just an initial load which takes a little while.

Comment: I ended up installing an SSD and purchasing the PSN digital version of the game. Loading times improved dramatically.